# No wifi connection on Debian 8 Gnome

Tags: debian, wifi

I have just installed debian 8 gnome desktop. I can not figure it out how to get wifi working. So I have wired internet using the modem cable, but there is no wifi device beeing detected under network manager. Can any one help?

These are some outputs from the link:

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
```

outputs

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59)
```

Comment: You need to provide some more details about your WiFi adapter for me to point you in the right direction.  I've had trouble with Broadcom adapters on Debian and Debian based systems.  Read through this, it looks to be a good resource, [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers).  Hope this helps

Comment: I have edited my question. Please see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular wifi hardware requires a non-free blob of firmware to work.

Running `apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree` should do the trick. If you get an error saying there's no such package, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list/` and change the line saying something like

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
```

to

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

and run `apt-get update` before trying again.

Comment: should this `apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` not be this `apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree`?

Comment: Oops, fixed. Well spotted.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, may I ask why?

Comment: it is not working , ( it wasn't me who downvoted ) , wifi working fine with ubuntu 16.04 -- 17.04 , I'm running debian 9.0.1